# how to link a form with one input submit with two links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I’m using [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co/) to send `html` information from my contact page

```
<form method="post" action = "https://formsubmit.co/ahmedoher01@gmail.com" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
```

to my email right now I used it and it works great and I used this code

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="www.paypal.com">
```

to go to another page after submmiting right now I wants to open a new blank after submitting as well , to explain more after the client submiting it go to
paypal and open a new page in blank for example google , thanks for all who is gonna help

Comment: @swati can you help?

Answer (score 4):

Button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256- 
WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="submitForm" method="post"></form>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" onclick="return onButtonSubmitClick()" 
name="submit" value="submit" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClick').on('click', function () {
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
            window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AhmedSyam isn’t this working. Be both have submitted same this.

Comment: @AhmedSyam you're added onButtonSubmitClick() function in your button ?

Comment: @AhmedSyam <button type="button" onclick=onButtonSubmitClick()>Submit</button>

Comment: ` <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ارسال" onButtonSubmitClick();> ` yes

Comment: @AhmedSyam change button type submit to button. and submit your form on buttonclick manually.

Comment: @AhmedSyam The way you write function in your input is wrong Please Follow this. <input type="button" name="submit" value ="ارسال" onclick="onButtonSubmitClick()" />

Comment: @Hrv so i will change the type of input from submit to button ?

Comment: @AhmedSyam Yes, and Follow jQuery i posted in Answer. $('#formID').submit(); this will submit your form manually

Comment: `<form method="post" action = "https://formsubmit.co/#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="forma" novalidate> ` it stopped the page there is no submtting happened ` <script>
      onButtonSubmitClick(){
          $('#forma').submit();
    window.open("www.Yourpage.com", "_blank"); 
}
  </script>`

Comment: @AhmedSyam Now see the code and do same as in your code.

Comment: @AhmedSyam Have you written`name="myform"` as @Hrv mention.